# Finding all related tables to a given table

Tags: sql

I'm working on a development with over 700 tables. I need to see a listing of all related tables to a given table. Can you recommend an app that is able to provide such a thing.

Comment: What version/make of SQL?  If it's Microsoft's, Management Studio can create a Diagram...

Answer (score 54):

If your database supports the information schema views (most do), then you can run this query:

```
SELECT
    c.CONSTRAINT_NAME,
    cu.TABLE_NAME AS ReferencingTable, cu.COLUMN_NAME AS ReferencingColumn,
    ku.TABLE_NAME AS ReferencedTable, ku.COLUMN_NAME AS ReferencedColumn
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.REFERENTIAL_CONSTRAINTS c
INNER JOIN INFORMATION_SCHEMA.CONSTRAINT_COLUMN_USAGE cu
ON cu.CONSTRAINT_NAME = c.CONSTRAINT_NAME
INNER JOIN INFORMATION_SCHEMA.KEY_COLUMN_USAGE ku
ON ku.CONSTRAINT_NAME = c.UNIQUE_CONSTRAINT_NAME
```

This will output a list of all referential constraints (foreign keys), the source (referencing) table/column, and primary key (referenced) table/column.

If you want to see references to a *specific* table, just add:

```
WHERE ku.TABLE_NAME = 'SomeTable'
```

Comment: Is it possible to select a single record and all its related records this way in sql server?

Answer (score 10):

Depending on the database product, you should be able to query the `INFORMATION_SCHEMA` views like so:

```
Select FK.TABLE_SCHEMA, FK.TABLE_NAME
From INFORMATION_SCHEMA.REFERENTIAL_CONSTRAINTS As RC
    Join INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS As PK
        On PK.CONSTRAINT_NAME = RC.UNIQUE_CONSTRAINT_NAME
    Join INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS As FK
        On FK.CONSTRAINT_NAME = RC.CONSTRAINT_NAME
Where PK.TABLE_SCHEMA = 'dbo'
    And PK.TABLE_NAME = '<target table name>'
```

Answer (score 1):

[MS Visio Pro](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/visio/HA101154851033.aspx) can do a good job of reverse engineering a db schema for a variety of databases (via ODBC) and provides a diagram that is very flexible.

Word of caution: Regardless of what system you use you do not want to pull in all 700 tables all at once. Try to create several diagram grouped and separated logically. Hopefully there will be many such groupings in a database that large.

Comment: Unfortunately this awesome feature was dropped in 2013.  2010 was the last version with it.

Answer (score 1):

In MS SQL Server you can use system stored procedure:

```
exec  sp_help 'table_name'
```

It show a lot of information about table and included list of the tables is referenced by foreign key.

Answer (score 0):

I use DataGrip diagrams with "Key columns" enabled and just "Columns" disabled. It's not a list of course, and I can't imagine how it looks like on a DB with 700 tables, but it's the most convenient way for me to see all relations between tables in my project.