# query to know a table is referenced to how many other table

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have recently started using Microsoft SQL Server and there is a below query which fetch the data from the table named tblPole , request you to please provide the query by which i can know that this table is referenced into how many other tables in database below is my query

```
select * from  [PDB_MASTER_ERT].[ter].[tblPole]
```

For all the tables relationship in databsae below is the query i am using

```
SELECT  obj.name AS FK_NAME,
    sch.name AS [schema_name],
    tab1.name AS [table],
    col1.name AS [column],
    tab2.name AS [referenced_table],
    col2.name AS [referenced_column]
FROM sys.foreign_key_columns fkc
INNER JOIN sys.objects obj
    ON obj.object_id = fkc.constraint_object_id
INNER JOIN sys.tables tab1
    ON tab1.object_id = fkc.parent_object_id
INNER JOIN sys.schemas sch
    ON tab1.schema_id = sch.schema_id
INNER JOIN sys.columns col1
    ON col1.column_id = parent_column_id AND col1.object_id = tab1.object_id
INNER JOIN sys.tables tab2
    ON tab2.object_id = fkc.referenced_object_id
INNER JOIN sys.columns col2
    ON col2.column_id = referenced_column_id AND col2.object_id = tab2.object_id
```

Comment: Just only one table. "[PDB_MASTER_ERT].[ter]" is schema, my friend.

Comment: @Tomato32 well PDB_MASTER_ERT is the database in which there is a table named tblPole, there are other tables also but rite now I am intrested for this table

Comment: You want to find all object that related tblPole table, right?

Comment: Whats wrong with the existing query that you have? Maybe you just need a `WHERE` on it

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid please advise you have suggested on the basis of second query, request you to please post the updated query with where clause so that I can grasp clearly

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Finding all related tables to a given table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2540315/finding-all-related-tables-to-a-given-table)

Comment: Add `WHERE tab1.name = 'tblPole'` to the end. A `WHERE` clause really is very basic. I suggest you go through this:https://www.w3schools.com/sql/default.asp

Answer (score 0):

Use this query:

```
SELECT  obj.name AS FK_NAME,
        sch.name AS [schema_name],
        tab1.name AS [table],
        col1.name AS [column],
        tab2.name AS [referenced_table],
        col2.name AS [referenced_column]
    FROM sys.foreign_key_columns fkc
    INNER JOIN sys.objects obj
        ON obj.object_id = fkc.constraint_object_id
    INNER JOIN sys.tables tab1
        ON tab1.object_id = fkc.parent_object_id
    INNER JOIN sys.schemas sch
        ON tab1.schema_id = sch.schema_id
    INNER JOIN sys.columns col1
        ON col1.column_id = parent_column_id AND col1.object_id = tab1.object_id
    INNER JOIN sys.tables tab2
        ON tab2.object_id = fkc.referenced_object_id
    INNER JOIN sys.columns col2
        ON col2.column_id = referenced_column_id AND col2.object_id = tab2.object_id
    where  tab1.name = 'tblPole'
```